# Prepare an NSDictionary from the data contained in two NSArrays for use in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, nsdictionary

I have searched extensively through SO and other sites for an answer... maybe I am missing something and/or don't understand the key/value coding structure of an `NSDictionary` properly?

I am programmatically preparing a `UITableViewController` in a custom controller class. I have two `NSArray`s that are built up in a fixed structure (of my choosing) by an iterative process from data persisted using Core Data.

**PROBLEM:** I want to combine two `NSArray`s into an `NSDictionary` so that I can use it in a `UITableView` and insert the appropriate data in the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` data source method using `NSIndexPath` references.

This is my view controller hierarchy...

- TVC  -->  inherits core data MOCs and sets global properties;
- TVC_List  -->  runs FRC to populate any list within a series of polymorphic table view controllers;
- TVC_Detail  -->  prepares a detail view for review/edit for a selected `NSManagedObject` from one of these lists;
- TVC_ContactDetail  -->  displays a detail view for review/edit for the selected `NSManagedObject` of type "Contact";
- TVC_AddressMethod  -->  takes the data from one entity relationship already held with strong reference for the selected `NSManagedObject` "Contact" with the intention of displaying in a custom built table view.

Yes I have considered using a separate FRC. The greater app uses a FRC for every other TVC through structured controller polymorphism and heirarchy.

I have attempted using a standalone FRC for this **special case** controller, however it does not seem to provide the flexibility I need regarding the **special case** data preparation I choose to use in this case. I have learned a lot about FRC and table views and their benefits and limitations but again, maybe I am missing something?

---

To explain in more detail...

I have a custom `NSManagedObject` ("`DD_AddressMethod`") that is passed to a controller. The custom `NSManagedObject` contains the data for contact information for the "contact".

For example it includes the following (Core Data model) entity attributes/relationships:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *data;
@property (nonatomic, retain) DD_Contact *contact;
@property (nonatomic, retain) DD_Type *type;
@property (nonatomic, retain) DD_TypeChild *typeChild;
```

*Note*: the three that commence with "`DD_`" are relationships to other custom `NSManagedObject`s.

I am able to programmatically construct the dynamic `UITableView` as per the following screenshot (for the iOS Contact "Daniel Higgins"). I am **not** able to properly allocate the data into the correct section:row:.

NOTE: to be clear, this screenshot is provided to detail the table view structure, however note that the data assigned to the labels is incorrect. It is for reference only.

[image: image of current incorrectly populated table view]

To continue my detailed description, the custom `NSManagedObject` is assigned to a strongly referenced variable.

From that I obtain two dynamically constructed `NSArray`s...

*Array No.1* : The section headers (which are extracted from the entity relationship "type"):

```
Printing description of mutableArraySectionHeaders:
<__NSArrayM 0x7b65e610>(
Telephone,
Facsimile,
Email
)
```

This dynamically constructed array provides the data to set values for my `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` and `tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:` data source methods.

*Array No.2* : The number of rows per section:

```
Printing description of mutableArrayRowNumbers:
<__NSArrayM 0x7b661ef0>(
2,
1,
1,
0
)
```

This dynamically constructed array provides the data to set the value for my `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` data source method.

**REITERATE PROBLEM:** What I want to achieve is the combination of these two dynamically constructed arrays (or similar arrays) into a dynamically constructed `NSDictionary` that can be used to populate cells within the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` data source method.

For example, something that creates a dictionary so that this line of code in my `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` data source method will work correctly...

```
cellData = self.dictionaryOfTwoArrays[indexPath];
```

I understand that the `NSDictionary` will be constructed of pairs. In this particular example the two arrays have a different number of elements, so for this particular example the dynamically constructed dictionary will need to drop the 0 from the *Array No.2*. But for another contact that for example does not have a "Facsimile" contact `type`, there might only be two pairs to insert into the dynamically constructed dictionary.

For information, note that the data itself is described as:

```
Printing description of mutableArrayAddressMethods:
<__NSArrayM 0x7b65d010>(
<DD_AddressMethod: 0x7b6e2140> (entity: AddressMethod; id: 0x7b644280 <x-coredata://C17E9176-4105-488B-86DA-3A94638E7FAF/AddressMethod/p3> ; data: {
    data = "555-478-7672";
    contact = "0x7b73b7a0 <x-coredata://C17E9176-4105-488B-86DA-3A94638E7FAF/Contact/p1>";
    type = "0x7b6d62c0 <x-coredata://C17E9176-4105-488B-86DA-3A94638E7FAF/Type/p60>";
    typeChild = "0x7b6a7670 <x-coredata://C17E9176-4105-488B-86DA-3A94638E7FAF/TypeChild/p54>";
}),
<DD_AddressMethod: 0x7b6d6530> (entity: AddressMethod; id: 0x7b6d3dc0 <x-coredata://C17E9176-4105-488B-86DA-3A94638E7FAF/AddressMethod/p4> ; data: {
    data = "(408) 555-5270";
    contact = "0x7b73b7a0 <x-coredata://C17E9176-4105-488B-86DA-3A94638E7FAF/Contact/p1>";
    type = "0x7b6d62c0 <x-coredata://C17E9176-4105-488B-86DA-3A94638E7FAF/Type/p60>";
    typeChild = "0x7b6436a0 <x-coredata://C17E9176-4105-488B-86DA-3A94638E7FAF/TypeChild/p23>";
}),
<DD_AddressMethod: 0x7b63f260> (entity: AddressMethod; id: 0x7b6abc20 <x-coredata://C17E9176-4105-488B-86DA-3A94638E7FAF/AddressMethod/p1> ; data: {
    data = "(408) 555-3514";
    contact = "0x7b73b7a0 <x-coredata://C17E9176-4105-488B-86DA-3A94638E7FAF/Contact/p1>";
    type = "0x7b6b72d0 <x-coredata://C17E9176-4105-488B-86DA-3A94638E7FAF/Type/p108>";
    typeChild = "0x7b6a7670 <x-coredata://C17E9176-4105-488B-86DA-3A94638E7FAF/TypeChild/p54>";
}),
<DD_AddressMethod: 0x7b64e890> (entity: AddressMethod; id: 0x7b6b4480 <x-coredata://C17E9176-4105-488B-86DA-3A94638E7FAF/AddressMethod/p2> ; data: {
    data = "d-higgins@mac.com";
    contact = "0x7b73b7a0 <x-coredata://C17E9176-4105-488B-86DA-3A94638E7FAF/Contact/p1>";
    type = "0x7b6dc6e0 <x-coredata://C17E9176-4105-488B-86DA-3A94638E7FAF/Type/p9>";
    typeChild = "0x7b6a7670 <x-coredata://C17E9176-4105-488B-86DA-3A94638E7FAF/TypeChild/p54>";
})
)
```

Comment: Is the titles correct but the content of the cells not? Can you paste the code generating the data to display?

Comment: The code that I use to generate `UITableViewCells` is incorrect - it is "something" to get the table view to load data. That is not the issue. The issue is the question, which is, how do I construct an `NSDictionary` from the two `NSArray`s shown, so that it can be used in the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` data source method... for example `addressMethod = self.dictionaryOfTwoArrays[indexpath];`, where `addressMethod` is then used to (correctly) populate the `UILabel`s in the table view cells.

Comment: Your arrays have different numbers of elements but a dictionary needs to be set up with pairs of things.  Is the 0 row numbers item to be ignored or should there be an extra section name?

Comment: Good point @PhillipMills. I'll update the question. The zero will be applied to a further section title that is missing in this particular example.

Comment: You seem to be trying to recreate what an NSFetchedResultsController will provide for free - have you considered that option?

Comment: @pbasdf yes have considered that option. The greater app uses controller polymorphism and hierarchy to populate table views using a FRC. This is a special case controller for which a FRC is not appropriate due to the way in which I choose to build the data structure.

Comment: Why do you want to use a dictionary as your TableView data source?

Comment: @HotLicks I don't necessarily need to use a dictionary as data source. It seems like a logical choice to me, because a dictionary can store nested arrays, which is by my understanding what I need to create, however maybe it is not appropriate?

Comment: An array can store nested arrays as well.  An array can store nested dictionaries.  Designing your data source is (at least) half the battle here.  Don't just assume -- ***plan***.

Comment: @HotLicks thanks for your suggestions. I have looked at many options on and off for the last four weeks. I have written out a number of different data structure approaches and plans on paper and in Xcode. I have spent hours reading tutorials and Apple documentation on Data Collections. In any case I understand that an array can store nested arrays and nested dictionaries - I have used those constructs in my code a number of times. For whatever reason, in this particular instance, I cannot seem to reconcile a solution. And it would seem to me that SO is not the place to find one.

Comment: Understand that a data source is not an incidental piece of support logic for a TableView.  Rather, a TableView is a visualization of the data source, and the data source comes first.  Design the data source first.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure if I've got question right, but anyway, maybe just try to combine all those models in two dimensions array, e.g. your helper (view-model) class might look like that:

```
@interface Helper

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *sections; // 2D array which contains arrays

@end

@implementation Helper

- (NSInteger)numberOfSections {
  return self.sections.count;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
  return [self.sections[section] count];
}

- (MVVMModel *)modelAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  return self.sections[indexPath.section][indexPath.row];
}

@end
```

and afterwards:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  id model = [self.helper modelAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @dktcup. I cannot seem to understand what you are suggesting. could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

If an FRC is out of the question, then this is the "brute force attack", so to speak, for your stated problem:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictionaryOfTwoArrays = [NSMutableDictionary new];
NSInteger arrayIndex = 0;
for (NSInteger sectionIndex = 0; sectionIndex < [mutableArrayRowNumbers count]; sectionIndex++) {
    NSInteger rowCount = [mutableArrayRowNumbers[sectionIndex] integerValue];
    for (NSInteger rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rowCount; rowIndex++) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowIndex inSection:sectionIndex];
        dictionaryOfTwoArrays[indexPath] = mutableArrayAddressMethods[arrayIndex];
        arrayIndex++;
    }
}
NSLog(@"dictionaryOfTwoArrays is %@",dictionaryOfTwoArrays);
```

You will obviously need to amend or rebuild this dictionary whenever the underlying mutable arrays change.  Also, note that your Array No.1 is irrelevant for these purposes, though you can still use it to populate the section titles.

The other option some have suggested in comments is an array of arrays.  That could be constructed along these lines:

```
NSInteger arrayIndex = 0;
NSMutableArray *sections = [NSMutableArray new];
for (NSInteger sectionIndex = 0; sectionIndex < [mutableArrayRowNumbers count]; sectionIndex++) {
    NSInteger rowCount = [mutableArrayRowNumbers[sectionIndex] integerValue];
    NSMutableArray *sectionRows = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (NSInteger rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rowCount; rowIndex++) {
        [sectionRows addObject:mutableArrayAddressMethods[arrayIndex]];
        arrayIndex++;
    }
    [sections addObject:sectionRows];
}
NSLog(@"Array of arrays is %@",sections);
```

You would then have to unpack your data with something like this:

```
NSArray *rowArray = sections[indexPath.section];
addressMethod = rowArray[indexPath.row];
```